# What causes the 'Add to playlist' button to not load playlists?

Tags: youtube

When uploading videos to YouTube using Firefox, I add them to relevant playlist(s) at the same time as doing the title, description, tags etc.

However, **perhaps 10-20% of the time** the `Add to playlist` dropdown just spins saying `Loading...` and doesn't load:

[image: yt playlist not loading]

*(Side note: I also see behaviour when creating a playlist via that dropdown- it will be created but not appear; I do this rarely so can't say how frequently it would happen)*

Other times the playlist dropdown will load and display successfully.

I've done some searches and some people suggest there is an issue if a video is unlisted, private or scheduled; but that's not the case here as can be seen from the image.

**What causes the dropdown to not load the list of playlists? Is there a way to prevent it happening?**

Comment: does it work in a different browser?

Comment: It works inconsistently in Firefox (pictured above), which I primarily use for managing this YT account. I can try another browser, but it's hard to replicate at will. (PS I will update the question with that info, thanks for that!)

Comment: do you have allowed javascript?

Comment: @user0 yes, I haven't disabled it as far as I'm aware. The dropdown loads normally 75% of the time (± 15%)